# cannot update table

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have 3 tables:

1. Vehicle_record
2. Insurance
3. Roadtax

While I'm succesful in updating the `vehicle_record` table, the other two tables cannot be updated.

When I run the query, the following error message appears:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE regno='TAC 2123'' at line 1

Comment: You need to post the code that produces the error

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, I suspect you have the key with date type a string. You should escape all values befor put it into the query.

I suggest you to try [AdoDB library](http://phplens.com/adodb/). This library is multi-database and will help you to easily do insert and update. Example of update using [AdoDB](http://phplens.com/adodb/):

```
$regno = $adodb->qstr('TAC 2123');
$data = array(
 'col1' => 'val1',
 'col2' => 'val2',
 'col3' => 'val3'
);
$result = $adodb->AutoExecute($tablename, $data, 'UPDATE', "regno=$regno");
```

By escaping the value before put it into a query, you can prevent the SQL injection attact. Doing it using [AdoDB](http://phplens.com/adodb/) Autoexecute, then the escape of values is doing automatically by [AdoDB](http://phplens.com/adodb/).

For the key with type string, you must do it manually. If the key is an integer, using `intval` is preferable than `$adodb->qstr()`.

Answer (score 0):

In order for us to help you here, you need to provide the full text of the SQL statement that is getting sent to the server. Paste it as a part of your question.